# How to view NWD of point cloud data with Forgeviewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I read point cloud data with Navisworks, output NWD, and converted it to SVF.
The results were as follows

{
 "type": "warning",
 "code": "Navisworks-PointUnsupported",
 "message": "Point and snappoint are not supported"
 },
 {
 "type": "warning",
 "code": "Navisworks-EmptyFile",
 "message": "There is no geometry that can be displayed"
 }

Does Forge not support point cloud data?
You can just view the point cloud data as a single object with Forgeviewer, but is that impossible? You don't even need attribute information, just look at it ...

Comment: sorry, Model Derivatives of Forge has not supported to translate [generic point cloud] yet, but the warning message you have would be [points and snap points] within a Navisworks file. Unless the model only contains [points and snap points], it shouldn't have any real impact on the translation. It's just saying it won't look exactly the same as what you see in Navisworks.

Comment: if [generic point cloud],  we have some blogs on how to import the points to the scene of Forge Viewer such as : https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/basic-point-clouds-forge-viewer

Comment: Thank you. Xiaodong
I will study a little more and try it out.